# Remove all characters that is not a number including period

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am not understanding of the replaceAll method works. More specifcally the first argument takes a string regex. I would like to remove all characters that is not a number, including periods.

my implementation.

```
    userId = inputRow.next().replaceAll("[\\.^\\d.]", "");
```

Sample output:

```
"","",""
"","",""
"","",""
"","BBLDX",""
"","N",""
"","",""
"","",""
"","",""
"","",""
"","",""
"","",""
"","",""
"","",""
"","",""
```

Its removing everything besides alphabets

Comment: It leaves behind only alphabetical characters. I just wanted the numbers. @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
userId = inputRow.next().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

[^\\d] will match all the character sequence which is not a number and replace it with empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You have error in regexp.
It should be "[^\\d]".
This will replace all characters that are not digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "afadsfas1234fasdfadsf.fasdf.sadfadsf.afadsf.5678";
System.out.println(text);
//  /D is equal to a non digit. [^0-9]
String result = text.replaceAll("[\\.\\D]", "");
System.out.println(result);
//Result will be 12345678
```

Above code will help you to remove all characters that is not a number, including periods. 
\d is for numbers 0-9 and \D is for non digit numbers.